# Статические методы Java

Tags: java

Возник такой вопрос, почему методы в основной программе являются статическими?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Вы про public static void main()?

Comment: @notaProgrammer Да

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Извините, такой вопрос мне задал преподаватель, и я понимаю, что он недостаточно подробен, но такой какой есть, преподаватель задал мне этот вопрос, я не смог ответить, но и сам он тоже не ответил.

Comment: Для того, чтобы JVM не пришлось создавать объект класса для запуска метода main()

Comment: @notaProgrammer Чёрт, действительно. Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Вот хорошая статья которая ответит на ваш вопрос
[10 заметок о модификаторе Static в Java](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/modifikator-static-java)